# .NET Chart Class - how to display different kind of intervals on the same chart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, intervals

I'm currently working on a project that I need to display a consolidate version of 2011 and 2012 data on this year's chart. This year's chart is monthly displayed.

This is my data. It's coming like this from the procedure, so no worries there:

```
Date        Value   Coefficient
01/01/2011  15,6    0,1586
01/01/2012  17,88   0,1468
01/01/2013  11,92   0,1872
01/02/2013  1703,85 0,17
01/03/2013  1693,49 0,16
01/04/2013  1716,1  0,17
01/05/2013  1732,31 0,17
01/06/2013  1692,79 0,17
01/07/2013  1691,38 0,17
```

See that the first two rows are the consolidate of the entire year, and the rest month by month.
The Value column should populate a column series attached to the primary Y-Axis. The Coefficient is a line attached to the secondary Y-axis.

I have this piece of code, that is currently showing everything messed up, with the monthly interval:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart4" runat="server" CssClass="Chart" BorderlineDashStyle="DashDotDot"
        Palette="Pastel" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource2" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
        Height="650px">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="value" XValueMember="date" Legend="Legend1"
                YValueMembers="value" YValueType="Double" ChartArea="ChartArea1" Color="CornflowerBlue"
                IsValueShownAsLabel="True" LabelFormat="{0:0.##}">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series Name="coef" XValueMember="date" Legend="Legend1" YValueMembers="coefCost"
                YValuesPerPoint="4" XValueType="Date" Color="YellowGreen" ChartType="Line" IsValueShownAsLabel="True"
                MarkerColor="Green" MarkerStyle="Diamond" YAxisType="Secondary" YValueType="Double"
                LabelFormat="{0:0.##\%}" BorderWidth="4" ChartArea="ChartArea1">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="Transparent" ShadowOffset="5">
                <AxisY Title="US$ / 1000">
                    <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                    <LabelStyle Format="{0:#,##0}" />
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX Interval="1" IntervalOffsetType="Months" IntervalType="Months">
                    <MajorGrid Enabled="False" IntervalOffsetType="Auto" IntervalType="Auto" />
                    <LabelStyle Interval="Auto" Format="{MMM/yy}" />
                    <ScaleBreakStyle Spacing="1" />
                    <ScaleView SizeType="Months" />
                </AxisX>
                <AxisX2>
                    <MinorGrid Enabled="True" />
                    <MajorTickMark Enabled="False" />
                </AxisX2>
                <AxisY2 Title="(%) Coef">
                    <MajorGrid Enabled="False" />
                </AxisY2>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="Legend1" Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom">
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
        <Titles>
            <asp:Title Font="Arial Narrow, 14pt" Name="Title1">
            </asp:Title>
        </Titles>
    </asp:Chart>
```

As you can see, I have the ObjectDataSource2 set to populate the series and, therefore, the chart.
I have already tried to mess with the interval things and all, but I couldn't achieve what I want.

This is a picture of what I got so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eYkn.png

To recap: I need this chart to display only what I bring back from my procedure. I know the problem is in the interval properties of the axis (interval monthly, interval = 1, etc), but I just can't seem to find a way around.

If someone has been through something similar and might have some pointers, that'd be great!

Thanks in advance!!!

**[EDITED]**

I got a little closer to what I need to achieve.

Check out this picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRYcX.png

I added this to the X-Axis (among other modifications to the properties, but this is what did the trick):

```
    <AxisX IntervalAutoMode="VariableCount" Interval="0">
```

... and it's "skipping" a few months by itself. Not sure where to go now, but I'm searching through the WebSamples application downloaded from MSDN (couldn't find the link, so sorry), maybe there's something there.

Comment: After spending almost the whole business day working on this, I finally found a workaround. Will post the final result first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here it goes.

I decided to rewrite the whole thing without using ObjectDataSource. 
I took all the properties off of Chart4 object (all that interval, monthly stuff and whatnot), and wrote everything on the code behind. I also had to format the X-Axis accordingly.

PS: I'm feeling kind of stupid cause I didn't think this through, and it doesn't look pretty, but since I've been struggling for three days straight, it'll have to do. Once I have some time, I'll re-factor and make it more elegant and efficient. Also, I'm so sorry this is VB.NET, I didn't have a saying on the choosing of the language lol.

Check it out:

```
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart4" runat="server" CssClass="Chart" BorderlineDashStyle="DashDotDot" Palette="Pastel" 
                ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation" Height="650px">
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="Legend1" Alignment="Center" Docking="Bottom">
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
        <Titles>
            <asp:Title Font="Arial Narrow, 14pt" Name="Title1">
            </asp:Title>
        </Titles>
    </asp:Chart>
```

On the back-end, this is what I did:

```
    Dim date As String
    Dim value As Double
    Dim coef As Double

    Dim chartArea As New ChartArea("chartEficOp")
    chartArea.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Transparent
    chartArea.ShadowOffset = 5

    Dim valueSeries As New Series("valueY")
    valueSeries.ChartArea = "chartEficOp"
    valueSeries.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4f81bd")
    valueSeries.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary
    valueSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    valueSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column
    valueSeries.Legend = "Legend1"
    valueSeries.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double

    Dim serieEfic As New Series("valueY2")
    coefSeries.ChartArea = "chartEficOp"
    coefSeries.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#9bbb59")
    coefSeries.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
    coefSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
    coefSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    coefSeries.Legend = "Legend1"
    coefSeries.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double
    coefSeries.BorderWidth = 4
    coefSeries.LabelFormat = "{0:0.##\%}"

    Dim targetSerie As New Series("0,15%")
    targetSerie.ChartArea = "chartEficOp"
    targetSerie.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red
    targetSerie.YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary
    targetSerie.IsValueShownAsLabel = False
    targetSerie.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    targetSerie.Legend = "Legend1"
    targetSerie.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double
    targetSerie.BorderWidth = 2
    targetSerie.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash

    Dim dt as DataTable = <called  the stored proc here>

    For Each item As DataRow In dt.Rows

        date = String.Format("{0:MMM/yy}", item("DATA"))

        Select Case <date here, to sort the x-label out>

            Case "01/01/2013"

                If date = "jan/11" Then
                    date = "2011"
                ElseIf date = "jan/12" Then
                    date = "2012"
                End If

            Case "01/01/2012"
                If date = "jan/11" Then
                    date = "2011"
                End If

        End Select

        value = item("VALUE")
        coef = item("COEF")

        valueSeries.Points.AddXY(date, value)
        coefSeries.Points.AddXY(date, coef)
        targetSerie.Points.AddXY(date, 0.15)

    Next

    Chart4.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea)

    Chart4.Series.Add(valueSeries)
    Chart4.Series.Add(coefSeries)
    Chart4.Series.Add(targetSerie)

    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1

    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "US$ / 1000"

    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Title = "% Cost"
    Chart4.ChartAreas(0).AxisY2.Interval = 0.04
```

... and the result was:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGKCa.png

Hopefully, this will help someone in the future.